# How can I inject factory into a filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a factory called

```
app.factory('$translation', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
       translate: function(input) { return input; }
    }
}]);

app.filter('translate', ['$translation', function($translation) {
    return function(input) {
        return $translation.translate(input);
    }
}]);
```

I keep getting:

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider $translation
```

How can I inject the factory into the filter?

Comment: Why you're giving factory name `$translation` ? Why don't you use `translation` ?

Comment: I just liked the naming. But it still doesn't work without the '$' sign. Already checked.

Comment: I created the plunker it's working :) http://plnkr.co/edit/KFtyOo4PVnI7leSRQCv5?p=preview

Comment: I got it to working now. I wasn't returning the function from inside the factory in my original code :P